# エラー：postfix is reserved

Tags: swift, xcode

ButtonをドラッグしてViewController.swiftにドラッグして「Action」に変更し、
`＠IBAction func tappedButton(sender: Any-Object){}`
というプログラムが追加された。

その後、tappedButtonメソッドの `{}` の中に `label. text = "ようこそ"` を記述し、
シミュレーターを起動しようとすると、　postfix is reserved 　とエラーがでてしまう。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: label. と text の間にスペースが入っていませんか？

Comment: ita_3yさんの言う通りスペースなくしたら無事解決しました！書籍どおりやっていて、スペースも正しいと勘違いするところでした。。。早々のご対応有難うございました！

Answer (score 1):

`label.` と `text` の間にスペースが入っていませんか？

**質問のコード**

```
label. text = "ようこそ"
```

**正しいコード**

```
label.text = "ようこそ"
```

---

*この投稿は [@ita_3y さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9845/%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc-postfix-is-reserved#comment8913_9845) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*